# Nothing is being returned

Tags: php

So, now, I can't seem to get this to work. What I'm trying to accomplish is to get the success message to show up, but it just doesn't work for some odd reason.

I'm using the php-login project (minimal) available here: http://www.php-login.net/

This is the basic PHP part.

```
<?php
    //die(print_r(get_defined_vars(), true));
    include("includes/database.incl.php");
    require_once("includes/Login.php");
    $login = new Login();
    if (isset($login)) {
        if ($login->errors) {
            if ($login->messages) {
                foreach ($login->messages as $message) {
                    die("success");
                }
            }
            foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
                echo $error;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo "nope";
    }
    $login = null;
?>
```

Right now, I'm using a program to send login details (log_name, log_password) using a POST request. It works and echos the errors if I deliberately put in wrong details, but once I type the details, it returns nothing. Even if I type incorrect details after, it still presents me with nothing.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a `]` in your code? typo? Also do you want a `die("success");` in a `foreach` loop or did you mean `echo("success");`

Comment: @Rizier123 - Oops. No, that's just Brackets breaking some things. It's actually `}` in the actual code. I did die, since I don't want multiple successes if something weird happens.

Comment: The code doesn't print anything if `$login->messages`is empty and `$login->errors` is empty. Without seeing the Login.php code it's hard to say why that would be.

Comment: @Juhana - a slightly modified version of https://github.com/panique/php-login-minimal; nothing big. just starting sessions automatically. I changed it to: `if ($login->messages) {
                foreach ($login->messages as $message) {
                    die("success");
                }
            } elseif($login->errors) {
                foreach ($login->errors as $error) {
                    echo $error;
                }
            } else {
                die("success");
            }` - still no dice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that it was a web server problem.

I was originally using XAMPP, and now that I switched to WAMP, it works.

Thanks for the help, everyone.